# How to hide border around TRadioGroup

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-2010

I have two radiobuttons in a **TRadioGroup**. All the logic behind how they are supposed to work is fine. But the **TRadioGroup** controler has a **frame** around it that I thought I would be able to delete using a **border** property or something like that. But the control doesn't seem to have any property that bears any resemblance to a border/frame. How do I set the controler to not include a frame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TRadioGroup` does not support what you are looking for.  Place two `TRadioButton` components onto a `TPanel` instead.  Then you can make it look how you want.

Comment: I thought this might be the case but somehow held on to the hope that the creators of RAD Studio actually had a brain :)... There must be millions of users who would like to have a group of radiobuttons but not be forced into having a frame. Ohhh no wait... millions... hmmm... Most have probably abandoned RAD Studio already :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can hide the border on a standard radio group box. It looks like you could create a custom descendant and override the painting if drawing normally, but that approach could be a bit more involved with theme support. Overall it sounds like a lot of work to go that route.

The next most obvious approach is to replace the radio group with a number of individual radio buttons on a container such as a panel. That would work and would be simple code but it could get messy. It seems a lot of busy work for little gain and I am lazy enough to look for another option.

There is a kludge you can use. If you put the radio group on a panel rather than directly onto the form (or other background) you can make the panel under-sized compared to the radio group. You want the panel to be as big as the interior of the radio group but not as big as the border. Then set the top and left of the radio group to negative numbers so that the border falls outside the parent panel. The border is not visible this way.

Comment: Good tip on using the undersized panel. Thanks. Also, make sure that BevelOuter of the Panel is set to bvNone.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not best practice but I had a similar issue and couldn't redesign everything.  So I did this to simply hide the border (and works great so far).

```
HANDLE Region = CreateRectRgn(3, 3, RadioGroup->Width-3, RadioGroup->Height-3) ;

SetWindowRgn(RadioGroup->Handle, Region, true);
```